# Deployment to AWS giving error "Unexpected token '<' in flutter.js"

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Flutter web app with a Go server deployed to an AWS EC2 instance through an AWS CodePipeline (for CI/CD). My EC2 setup is `Go 1 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.7.2`.

The Flutter web app runs correctly when launched on a local server or when using the `flutter run --release` command. However, when deployed to my EC2 instance, I get the following blank page with the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at flutter.js:1:1)` displaying in the console (note: the next error, `_flutter is not defined` is caused by the first error).

[image]

Oddly, when I look at the `flutter.js` file to which the error is referring, that file shows the wrong content; it shows the content of the `index.html` file, which indeed has a `<` character in line 1:1 as the error points out.

[image]

As the next step, I look at my EC2 instance (via SSH) to view the `flutter.js` file that I deployed. The deployed file is the correct one, not the one that the console error points out.

[image]

So what is going on here? Is this a setup issue or a compatibility issue with deploying a Flutter Web app to an AWS Go server? If of any help, below is the full index.html file.

Note: I haven't been able to find solutions in other similar issues posted here on SO or elsewhere.

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="test_app_1">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>test_app_1</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        entrypointUrl: "/main.dart.js",
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
          serviceWorkerUrl: "/flutter_service_worker.js?v=",
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Don't paste images of code or other text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860)

Comment: The response content for `flutter.js` is not the same as the `index.html` file you posted. Have you found out where does it come from? For an SPA web application, the web server will be configured to serve the `index.html` file if the request is not an API request (or something  else whitelisted). So you should check how the web server is configured. The common set up is: 1. if the request is an API request, pass it to the API handler; 2. if the path of the request has an extension, and there is a file found in the file system, serve it; 3. otherwise, serve the `index.html` file.

Comment: @ZekeLu the response content is actually the same as the index.html, I had just removed the comments of the file for ease of read. See updated index.html. I checked the web server and it is indeed configured to serve index.html, so that doesn't seem to be the cause.

Comment: `I checked the web server and it is indeed configured to serve index.html, so that doesn't seem to be the cause`. I don't understand. Will the server serve the content of `index.html` for url path `/path/to/flutter.js`? If yes, this is the cause. The problem is in the web server side. Please share how the web server (or web application) is configured.

Answer (score 0):

In case it can be of help to anyone else, the cause of this issue was the following:

Aside from the `index.html` file, Elastic Beanstalk’s default web configuration does not serve any static files (i.e. any of the Flutter web app files). More info about that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-cfg-staticfiles.html).

Therefore in my case, it was not serving the `flutter.js` file or any other static files from the Flutter web app build. Furthermore, instead of returning a `404 page not found` error, it was returning the `/index.html` page due to a secondary issue (had my Chi router incorrectly set up to render the index page for any non-available url paths).

As instructed in the above link, I added the following file and code to the app source code, ensured that it is deployed correctly, and it works fine now.

**.ebextensions/static-files.config**

```yaml
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /assets: assets
    /canvaskit: canvaskit
    /flutter.js: flutter.js
    /main.dart.js: main.dart.js
    /flutter_service_worker.js?v=: flutter_service_worker.js
```